# Performance and Memory wise is JPG or PNG better for Core Image?

Tags: ios, png, jpeg, core-image

The title pretty much sums up the question but I was wondering if JPG/PNG files have a notable difference in speed and performance when using `CIFilter`s. Is using one type of file preferred over the other? Is there another file type that could be potentially faster than both JPG and PNG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. JPEG and PNG are storage mechanism. Filters have to be performed on uncompressed data, not on JPEG or PNG streams.
2. The speed difference between JPEG and PNG occurs reading or writing. PNG compression generally is slower than JPEG compression. PNG expansion is generally faster than JPEG.
3. JPEG is not suitable for images that have abrupt changes in color, e.g. drawings, cartoons.
4. JPEG is not suitable for images that are stored, retrieved, modified, stored . . . . Each cycle changes the image.
5. JPEG generally produces much smaller compressed streams than PNG.

Comment: So does that mean a PNG is suitable as using it with a filter would involve storing, retrieving, modifying, and storing?

Comment: If you do JPEG => FILTER FILTER FILTER ... => JPEG you have no problem. If you do JPEG => FILTER => JPEG => FILTER => JPEG . . . you could run into problems.

Comment: Ohhhhh that makes a lot more sense now :)! That means I am good

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends! PNG's are better if it is a smaller image, as it cuts away the white surrounding what is actually there. But, it does not compress at all to maintain quality. This could slow down performance. JPEG compresses, therefore cutting down file size, but also compromising quality to a point. I'd say go for JPEG if it is a huge image for the app, but go for PNG if you want quality.

Thanks for asking and hope this helps. If this answers your question, I'd love if you could just hit that check mark.

Cheers,
Theo

Comment: Also, is there a big difference in quality or is it almost unnoticeable to the human eye?

Comment: This answer assumes that `CIFilter` works on the raw PNG or JPEG which is unlikely.

Comment: Hi Harish, sorry I did not see these. Difference in quality is probably unnoticable unless the image is large, then you will probably be able to see the pixels,

Comment: The kind of image data you are compressing is what matters. JPEG is for photos and it is a lossy approach. PNG is lossless and is designed more for line art and color tables that are generally small (meaning not images). Different input demands different encoding approaches.